# What is the integral trick for a Coulomb potential?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I recall reading in Feynman and Hibbs about an integration
trick that can be used to solve certain types of integrals
that involve the Coulomb potential.
What was the trick?

Comment: This question is too vague for anyone but you to answer. Are you looking for someone else to answer this, or do you just want a place to write down your own answer? If the latter, it is a little rude to do this in a public forum since your questions are presented to everyone in the community.

Comment: @hft It is actually allowed to answer your own question. We also encourage users to do so. However, you are right that we question itself is only useful to the OP (as it is not clear what exactly is asked for) and hence off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is,
multiply the integrand by $\exp(-\epsilon r)$, solve the integral,
then let $\epsilon\rightarrow0$.

For example, consider the following momentum transfer function
where $\breve p=p_a-p_b$.
$$
v(\breve p)=\frac{4\pi\hbar}{\breve p}
\int_0^\infty \sin\left(\frac{\breve pr}{\hbar}\right)V(r)r\,dr
$$

For the Coulomb potential $V(r)=-Ze^2/r$ we have
$$
v(\breve p)=-\frac{4\pi\hbar Ze^2}{\breve p}
\int_0^\infty \sin\left(\frac{\breve pr}{\hbar}\right)\,dr
$$

The integral diverges so use the trick.
$$
v(\breve p)=-\frac{4\pi\hbar Ze^2}{\breve p}
\int_0^\infty \sin\left(\frac{\breve pr}{\hbar}\right)\exp(-\epsilon r)\,dr
$$

Solve the integral.
$$
v(\breve p)=-\frac{4\pi\hbar Ze^2}{\breve p}
\;\frac{\breve p/\hbar}{(\breve p/\hbar)^2+\epsilon^2}
$$

Let $\epsilon\rightarrow0$.
$$
v(\breve p)=-\frac{4\pi\hbar^2Ze^2}{\breve p^2}
$$